# Does Hive have a String split function?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am looking for a in-built String split function in Hive? e.g. if String is:

```
A|B|C|D|E
```

Then I want to have a function like:

```
array<string> split(string input, char delimiter)
```

So that I get back:

```
[A,B,C,D,E]
```

Does such a in-built split function exist in Hive.

I can only see `regexp_extract` and `regexp_replace`. I would love to see a `indexOf()` and `split()` string functions.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There does exist a split function based on regular expressions.  It's not listed [in the tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive/Tutorial#Built_in_functions), but it is listed on [the language manual on the wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions):

```
split(string str, string pat)
   Split str around pat (pat is a regular expression)
```

In your case, the delimiter "`|`" has a special meaning as a regular expression, so it should be referred to as "`\\|`".

Comment: semicolon is not in the list of regex metacharacters (see, e.g., https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php). Thus, you should just be able to use ';' instead of '\\;'.

Comment: The page does not exist anymore: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/Hive/LanguageManual/UDF#String_Functions

Comment: up to date Language Manual link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions

Answer (score 53):

Another interesting usecase for split in Hive is when, for example, a column `ipname` in the table has a value "abc11.def.ghft.com" and you want to pull "abc11" out:

```
SELECT split(ipname,'[\.]')[0] FROM tablename;
```

Comment: is the split can use in `GROUP BY` like `select split(area,'[_]')[0],isp,pc_mobile,device,count(userip) from usemap_without_ptime ORDER BY split(area,'[_]')[0],isp,pc_mobile,device`

Comment: Actually you  have to put the pattern in a regex. should be SELECT split(ipname,'\\.')[0] FROM tablename

Answer (score 13):

Just a clarification on the answer given by Bkkbrad.

I tried this suggestion and it did not work for me.

For example,

```
split('aa|bb','\\|')
```

produced:

```
["","a","a","|","b","b",""]
```

But,

```
split('aa|bb','[|]')
```

produced the desired result:

```
["aa","bb"]
```

Including the metacharacter '|' inside the square brackets causes it to be interpreted literally, as intended, rather than as a metacharacter.

For elaboration of this behaviour of regexp, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html