# Hive function to replace comma in column value

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive table which has String column having value as 12,345. Is there any way hive function which can remove comma during insertion in this hive table ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace(string INITIAL_STRING, string PATTERN, string REPLACEMENT)` which is a function in Hive.

So if you are moving the data from a table that contains the comma to a new table you will use :
`insert into table NEW select regexp_replace(commaColumn,',','') from OLD;`

Answer (score 0):

Hive does have split function. which can be used here. split and concat to achieve the desired result
You may refer this question.
[Does Hive have a String split function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065999/does-hive-have-a-string-split-function)