# converting values from string to int in hive

Tags: casting, hive

I am creating a table in hive;

```
create table patients(
  patient_id INT,
  age_group STRING,
  gender STRING,
  income_range STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ';

load data local inpath '/mnt/patients.csv' into table patients;
```

Now when I am using the command:

```
hive>select * from patients limit 5;
```

I am getting the output:

```
NULL    75-84,  F,      32000-47999
NULL    75-84,  M,      16000-23999
NULL    85+,    M,      <16000
NULL    65-74,  F,      32000-47999
NULL    <65,    M,      <16000
```

But when I am using assigning patient_id as string its showing:

```
 910997967,      75-84,  F,      32000-47999
 506013497,      75-84,  M,      16000-23999
 432041392,      85+,    M,      <16000
 633048699,      65-74,  F,      32000-47999
```

I tried to use :

```
 hive>select CAST(patient_id AS int) from patients;
```

But its not changing the values to int and only showing

```
NULL
NULL
...
```

How could the values of patient_id can be converted to int values?

Thanks

Comment: It seems you have a comma as a part of the data. I would suggest to take care of it while loading the data into the table. Once the comma is removed from the string, the `CAST` will work correctly.

Comment: First make sure the delimiter you are using is correct w.r.t your csv file.
Second check your int/double/float values in csv file, they should not have **""** in the file.
In your case it seems the problem of delimiters as @visakh pointed out.

Comment: @visakh:thanks a lot.your observation helped me

Answer (score 2):

As @visakh pointed out that there is a comma(,) in your 1st column: patient_id.

You need to remove this.

You may use

```
    CAST(regexp_replace(patient_id, ',' , '') AS INT)
```

This is similar to 
[Hive function to replace comma in column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501574/hive-function-to-replace-comma-in-column-value)