# Hive Split function to split a variable on \n

Tags: regex, split, hive

**Task**: I want to split a variable called "website" in a hive table to get all the websites that are delimited by character space or \n

**Issue**: When I use either of the following queries:

```
SELECT website,split(website, '[\\s]') as websites FROM temp_pages
SELECT website,split(website, '[\\s, \\n]') as websites FROM temp_pages
```

I am unable to achieve the desired results.
Here are the results that I get

***Expected Output*** - delimited on **space**
**Input**: http://www.insync4all.com http://www.insync4all.nl
**Output**: ["http://www.insync4all.com","http://www.insync4all.nl"]

***Unexpected output*** - Delimited  on **\n**.
When there is an \n character instead of splitting the websites based on \n character it introduces \\n

**Input**: www.imtherealthing.com\nwww.childmodelmagazine.com
**Output**: ["www.imtherealthing.com\\nwww.childmodelmagazine.com"]

Can someone help me to split the website field on \n. It will also be good to understand what is going wrong in the \n case.

Comment: Maybe this thread can help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065999/does-hive-have-a-string-split-function

Comment: Thanks but I have already checked this and my question is different