# How to extract second word in a string in SQL separated by underscore?

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to extract only the second word in a string.
For example

```
Name[Column Name]
Patrick_Andrew_Marsh
Rajesh_Kumar_Sinha
```

I want to extract Andrew and Kumar from the column and similarly for all the other names. How do I do it?

Comment: http://hadooptutorial.info/string-functions-in-hive/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Hive have a String split function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065999/does-hive-have-a-string-split-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` function for this purpose

```
 select split(name, '_')[1]  from table
```